# Finding E(YX) from a table

Tags: probability

Taking this table as an example of how would one be able to find E(XY)
[image: Table with numbers]
I know that if X and Y are independent then:
$$E(XY) = E(X)*E(Y)$$

What method should be used if one doesn't know if X and Y are independent?

Thank you very much for your response.

*(In this case, the answer is 12)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know if the variables are independent, just use the definition of expectation:
$$E[XY]=\sum_{x,y}xyP(X=x,Y=y)=2\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{8}+2\cdot 3\cdot \frac{1}{24}+...=12$$

Comment: In fact, we know the variables *are dependent*, since $\mathsf P(X=4, Y=9)=0$.